# Eclipse Luna CDT C++11 lambda code formatting

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

Does anyone know of a fix for the Eclipse Luna CDT horrible lambda code auto formatting? When I write a C++11 lambda inside a function, and run a code auto-format, the resulting formatting is just off, `for` loops do not indent, the closing brace of the lambda is not aligned with the opening one etc. Is this a known issue? Wasn't able to find any fix/solution.

Comment: There are more C++11 things that don't *yet* work in Eclipse - for example Eclipse doesn't understand alignof() keyword. Lack of auto-formatting for lambdas is just the result of the previous issue - Eclipse doesn't know what this construct is, so it doesn't know how to treat it and format it.

Comment: @FreddieChopin I thought the latest CDT (8.4.0) has full support for C++11, at least I am not getting any warnings/errors about C++11 keywords (like `override` etc), however the support for lambda's is bad in the code formatter.

Comment: Well, my 8.5.0 doesn't have that full C++11 support (; - I have an example code right in front of me and alignof() is treated by Eclipse like a regular function. This is annoying, because I use it for std::aligned_storage<>, which leads to the whole statement being treated as error and all uses of such object are also considered errors... If you want to talk about formatting issues, Eclipse also doesn't like the new unified initialization - if you omit the '=' and use multiline initialization, Eclipse doesn't auto-format that correctly either (it is treated more like a function body).

Comment: @FreddieChopin thanks much, hope CDT will eventually improve.